# Vaadin Flow Grid. scroll to item programmatically

Tags: vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

After selecting an item programmatically I want to scroll to them.

How can I scroll to selected item programmatically in Vaadin 10?

I did not found any method to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature has not been implemented yet, there is feature request here

https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-flow/issues/289

But it is possible to do this with JavaScript call, e.g. like this

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("$0._scrollToIndex($1)", grid, row)
```

Threre is more discussion here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17215099

Comment: Do you know how I could determine the current scroll position to restore it later?